# login validation with response from controller

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, sails.js

I am using simple validation for login page. In the controller i have used the validation conditions.

LoginController.js

```
login : function(req,res) {

   var username = req.param('username');
   var password = req.param('password');
   console.log("user : " + username + " : " + password);
   Login.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, usr) {
     if (err) {
            res.send(500, { error: "DB Error" });
        } else {
            if (usr) {
                      console.log("found user : " + usr.username + " password : " + usr.password)
                if (password == usr.password) {
                    req.session.user = usr;
                    res.send(200,usr);
                } else {
                    res.send(400, { error: "Wrong Password" });
                }
            } else {
                res.send(404, { error: "User not Found" });
            }
        }
   });
```

These errors are displayed in the server side, like in run time to show these error in User Interface(UI) with the `res`in the react file

LoginForm.jsx

```
signin: function() {
    console.log("in Signin");
    var username = this.refs.username.value.trim();
    var password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
    this.onSubmit({username: username, password: password});
    this.refs.password.value = '';
  },

  onSubmit: function(login) {
    var username = this.refs.username.value.trim();
    var password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
    socket.post(this.props.url, login, function whenServerResponds(usr) {
    console.log(usr);

    ///    how to correct it

    if(res.usr){alert("login success");}else{
    if(res.getResponseHeader("error")){alert("password incorrect");}
    else{alert("user not found")}

    ///
    }
    });
  },
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here.  Can you clarify how you want this to work, and how the behavior with your current code isn't meeting your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

This format is not gonna work `res.send(200,usr);`

Try to send in exact format like this

```
login: function(req, res) {

  var username = req.param('username');
  var password = req.param('password');
  console.log("user : " + username + " : " + password);
  Login.findOne({
    username: username
  }, function(err, usr) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({
        error: "DB Error"
      });
    } else {
      if (usr) {
        console.log("found user : " + usr.username + " password : " + usr.password)
        if (password == usr.password) {
          req.session.user = usr;
          res.status(200).send(usr);
        } else {
          res.status(400).send({
            error: "Wrong Password"
          });
        }
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({
          error: "User not Found"
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And access your user object or error

Comment: will you tell how to use it in LoginForm.jsx    file                                      available above

Comment: Check you ` console.log(usr);` value and plz post here